# Show circle off a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have a RelativeLayout where I Inflate the current view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/selected_background"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:translationX="-5dp"
        android:translationY="-5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selected_edge_circle"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

selected_background is a drawable:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

and the selected_edge_circle:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
  <size android:width="25dp" android:height="25dp"/>
  <solid android:width="3dp" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

I'm getting this result:
[image]

As you can see the circle is cut-of, although I ahve specified not to clip it. I want to show a circle on the top left corner that looks like this:

[image]

I don't want to wrap this Layout in another container and set a padding or a margin, I want, no matter what, overflow the top left circle. Any ideas who this can be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the way you want it. I believe it is a way of doing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/selected_background"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp">

        <View
            android:translationX="-5dp"
            android:translationY="-5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selected_edge_circle"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Amazing, that did the trick. Thank you very much for the answer!